# error encountered when open jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is the type of error I am getting after running this command

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Jupyter Notebook localhost`localhost:8888` WINDOW RUNNING MY CODE

```
[I 07:27:27.681 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/dsm/alx
0 active kernels
Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:
http://localhost:8888/?token=24aa9fc8b381e38bce8482e2dcc88414fa94a2eec29f3799
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=24aa9fc8b381e38bce8482e2dcc88414fa94a2eec29f3799
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the command that really helped me

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```